# Как лучше передавать кучу параметров?

Tags: c#

Есть метод в который нужно передавать параметры, внутри этого метода я эти параметры присваиваю

```
public static string SendMessage(string text, string apilToken, string login, string, password, bool checker, string destID)
{
   string urlString = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{apilToken}/sendMessage?chat_id={destID}&text={text}";
   if (checker)
   {
     // ....
   }
   // ...
}
```

Точно не знаю, но хочу чтобы меня просветили как можно делать а как нельзя...

Можно ли как-то создать словарь допустим:

```
public static string SendMessage(Dictionary<string, object> keys)
{
   keys = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   // и тут уже присваивать нужные значения через keys ?
}
```

Или же будет проще создать класс со свойствами и использовать его?

Comment: Если в объекте скапливается много значений определенной категории, то делайте класс, который все это будет содержать, тогда у вас будет не ваша длинная портянка, а например `public static string SendMessage(SendData data){ ... data.Token ... }`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Только чтобы вбить параметры в `SendData data` будет такая же длинная строка. Если эти параметры используются единично при вызове метода, то нет смысла использовать класс.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Мы говорим об удобстве или сокращение? Если о сокращение, то простите, как вы сократите "вася@почта.ру" и "12345"? Вам так или иначе придется их писать, где бы то не было. Если же мы говорим про удобство, то обычно такие классы данных создаются раз и все, дальше в них лишь меняется нужная информация, а по поводу строки - создайте некий билдер и пусть он по вызову `data.Buld()` выдает эту строку, удобно? Да. Сократили мы повторное использование таких конструкций - да. Так что простите, класс есть смысл использовать всегда, где это надо, не гоже в 1-м месте хранить все.

Comment: Если строго следовать канонам ООП, то желательно создать отдельный класс. Более того, следует отказаться от примитивных типов наподобие `string`: [Primitive Obsession](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession/) (и там по ссылке статейка побольше).

Comment: Однако, в последнее время есть тенденция ухода от ООП в сторону функциональщины и других парадигм. В итоге лишняя структура данных может не поощряться.